# Using OpenCv with no image proccessing background to detect objects on a pavement to avoid them

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'm a Software Engineering student in my last year in a 4-year bachelor degree program, I'm required to work on a graduation project of my own choice.

we are trying to find a way to notify the user of any thing the gets on his/her way while walking, this will be implemented as an android application so we have the ability to use the camera, we thought of Image processing and computer vision but neither me or any of my group members have any Image processing background, we searched a little bit and we found out about OpenCv.

So my question is do I need any special background to deal with OpenCv? and is it a good choice for the objective of my project to use computer vision, if not what alternatives do u advise me to use?

I appreciate your help.. thanks in advance!

Comment: opencv is a very well documented c++ library and tons of examples, blogs, open source projects are there for you to get used to it. search for "motion detection", "background subtraction" and "frame difference" algorithms for your case. another approach would be "histogram comparison". good luck.

Comment: Although OpenCV is a very good imaging library, I think what you're trying to achieve is way too complicated if you have no prior knowledge in computer vision.

Comment: I want to thank you both for your helpful replies, and sorry i didn't reply earlier.

Answer (score 1):

At the first glance I would use 2 standard cameras to find depth image - stereo vision (similar to MS Kinect depth sensor)

from that it would be easy to fix a threshold to some distance.

Those algorithms are very CPU hungry so I do not think it will work on Android (although I have zero experience).

I you must use Android, I would look for some depth sensor (to avoid extracting depth data from 2 images)

For prototyping I would use MATLAB (or Octave), then I would switch to OpenCV (pointers, mem. allocations, blah...)